# typescript: cannot apply parseInt() to a string in HTTP request header

Tags: typescript

In typescript, I try to get an attribute from the http request header.

The attribute is a string (of course, it is from the header), I need to parse it into Integer

```
export const getUser =  async (req, _res, next) => {
  
  const userId: number = parseInt(req.headers.userid);
  
  ... other code 
}
```

However, the vs code IDE is displaying red line under `req.headers.userid` and complaining:

```
(property) IncomingMessage.headers: IncomingHttpHeaders
Argument of type 'string | string[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
```

How can I do this simple task?

Comment: Show some more code or even playground link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message says your variable is typed `string | string[] | undefined`, but `parseInt` requires `string`. So you have to handle the other types that `userid` could be.

Maybe something like:

```
const userIdHeader = req.headers.userid
if (typeof userIdHeader === 'string') {
  const userId = parseInt(userIdHeader);
}
```

Now you can only reach that code in the case where you have a string, and typescript knows it.

So [the docs on narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the exact same problem and I solved by:

```
const userIdHeader = req.headers.userid;
const userId = parseInt(String(userIdHeader));
```

Or better:

```
const userId = parseInt(String(req.headers.userid));
```